# How to find the row number of a dataset vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I am trying to find the row number of a dataset that holds the item "Rushil" in the field "Name". I was researching how to do this and I came across the Datatable.Select method.

What would the filter expression be to find the row number? How would I do this in vb.net?

Comment: What do you mean for _row number_? The position of the row in the whole datatable?

Comment: @Steve In SQL, I can write a query fetching the "ROWNUM". By row number, I mean whether the record is on the first row of a table within a database, the second row etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **vb.Net**

```
'assume that you want to start indexing from 1
Dim rowNum As Integer
rowNum = 0
For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
    If LCase(Trim(row.Item("Name"))) = LCase("Rushil") Then
        Exit For
    End If
    rowNum += 1
Next row
If rowNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox("Rushil was found at " + Str(rowNum + 1))
Else
    MsgBox("Rushil was not found")
End If
```

---

Using **SQL SERVER**

According to your question I assume there's only one 'Rushil' in the table, and then I'll tell you how to get the row number of a single row in a table.

```
select rank 
from(select rank() OVER (ORDER BY e.[name]) as rank,e.[name] 
from example e)z 
where [name]= 'Rushil'

/* result : */

rank    
2
```

how to approach the answer

```
create table example(
    [name] varchar(10),
    password varchar(8)
)

insert into example values('veteranlk','password')
insert into example values('sqlfiddle','wasspord')
insert into example values('Gholkar','qwedsadd')
insert into example values('Rushil','ssdwwaaa')
insert into example values('Shirul','wasspord')

select rank() OVER (ORDER BY e.[name]) as rank,e.[name]
from example e
order by rank

/* result : */

rank    name
1       Gholkar
2       Rushil
3       Shirul
4       sqlfiddle
5       veteranlk
```

Comment: cheers, but I was asking how to do this in vb.net (sorry, I didn't make that clear), not sql.

Comment: do you still need to use a dataTable? Its like getting the whole table over the network to the client computer and then analyzing at client end. Let SQL server handle them. Lower network traffic as much as you can by getting the rows you only need. please refer datareader ( datareader=command.ExecuteQuery() ) .. sorry I was through my mobile phone, couldnt format the comment

Comment: I can't use SQL Server - I don't have it installed... nor can I install it, because of permissions.

Comment: I just updated my code by adding VB too. you can now accept that